# optocoupler - Does the current limiting resistor of the led make a difference

Tags: opto-isolator

Does the led  current limiting resistor for the led make a difference to the performance/behaviour of the optocoupler?

Is it just like how a normal transistor would work, if you drive the base harder, you will get more current flowing between emitter and collector?

I understand you mustn't drive the led too hard otherwise you let magic smoke out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has the same properties of wide tolerance to hFE of a transistor except a coupling loss that reduces it to a small fraction.

Just as hFE can vary considerably with Ic and Vce, so too can opto-coupled transistors.
Generally hFE is reduced to 5 to 10% of the max value when Vce=Vce(sat)  so it depends if you are using the device as a linear or logic level for tolerances of expected results and performance (f, slew rate or BW)

Photo Diodes are very consistent, while transistor hFE is not and may exceed a 2:1 range unless you choose the better parts.  IR LEDs are very consistent for Vth forward threshold at 1V @ 25'C but can vary somewhat in Vf at rated current depending on design of power and also 20% due to wide temperature range.

LED output power efficacy or optical power can decline with age so you must consider this in your worst case margin calculations.  This also depends on how hot you drive them as aging increases with self heating as they are very small chips.  Generally low current is recommended such as 5mA but too low (<10% max) can also cause threshold issues.

Photo-transistors have an extremely wide range Current Transfer Ratio or CTR (which includes the single transistor or darlington hFE and coupling loss)

e.g. from DigiKey

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If there is no resistor, too much current flows destroying the LED. That's why there is a current-limiting resistor. The LED also needs at least some amount of current for it to work at all and take LED aging into account, but in general, brighter LED means more transistor current flows, a parameter called the current transfer ratio (CTR).

Comment: yes I understand. Let say the maximum the led can take is 30ma. Would it be exactly the same if I sized the resistor pass 3ma of current as oppose to 10ma

Comment: the datasheet will list "current transfer ratio" which is much like \$h_{FE}\$ in transistors

Comment: so if you give the led more current, the transistor side will allow more current to flow?

Comment: yes it's like that. but using a smaller current can extend the life of the LED in the optocoupler, so there's a trade-off.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the led current limiting resistor for the LED make a difference to the performance/behaviour of the opto-coupler?

Yes. It will determine the maximum current that can be delivered by the transistor.

> Is it just like how a normal transistor would work, if you drive the base harder, you will get more current flowing between emitter and collector?

In general, yes. Remember that the current may be limited by something else, such as the resistance of the load or the power-supply.

The information below is published in the [Vishay 4N25](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83725/4n25.pdf) datasheet. As always, in most applications certain parameters become more significant than others. Careful reading of the datasheets and experience will be your guide.

[image]

*Figure 1. Details from the datasheet.*

[image]

*Figure 2.  Current transfer ration (CTR) as a function of LED current. Note datasheet has CTR curves for other temperatures also.*

Table 1 and Figure 2 show us that for this device when the LED is run at 10 mA we can expect to get only 2 to 5 mA maximum out of the transistor. If more current is required then further amplification is required – e.g., the Darlington arrangement shown at the top of this page.

In most applications we design the circuit to drive the output transistor into saturation.

> I understand you mustn't drive the led too hard otherwise you let magic smoke out.

Yes this is the same as any other infrared LED.

I've written further on the topic in [opto-couplers](http://lednique.com/opto-isolators-2/opto-isolators/) and you may find the article helpful.